# How to do relation extraction for entity centric search engine?

Tags: lucene, indexing, entity, search-engine, relationship

I'm building a Entity centric search engine. Here is what i have done so far.

- Identified all entities in a document like person, email id etc using Stanford's Named Entity Recognizer.
- Built a entity based index table using Lucene indexer like "Barack Obama" with field name "PERSON" and also keyword based index.

Now, I need to establish relationships between those entities. For example, if the query is like "Wife of Obama", i need to resolve that to Michelle Obama. I want two entities "Barack Obama" and "Michelle Obama" linked by relation "spouse". I referred several papers for relation extraction but in vain.I don't want to extract data from already existing one like from "Freebase", I want to extract on my own using some algorithms or api.
Please suggest an idea or a way to build relation table.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Relationship extraction well known problem in NLP field and can be handled with kernal mathed.
This problem can be easily transformed into a classification problem and you can train a model for every relation ship type.

What you have to do is first extract entities from the Wikipedia page.
and perform conference  resolution for every entity (pronoun replacement).
Then you have to extract feature for the relationship type for which you want to train your model

lets try it with a toy example.

American Airlines, a unit of AMR, immediately matched the move, 
spokesman Tim Wagner said.

here you have two entity in  the artical person and orgnization

relation is person - spokesman - org.

for this relation you can extract this fetaures

1- entity based features 
entity1 type - ORG (can be find out by Gazetteer or named entity extarction tool)
entity1 head - airline
entity2 type - PERSON  (can be find out by Gazetteer or named entity extarction tool)
entity2 head - Wagner
concatenated types - ORGPER

2- word based features :
 bagofwords between entity , word before entity1 , word after entity2 , bigram before entity1, bigram after entity1, bigram before entity2, bigram after entity2

3- syntatic features:
  poss tag of word before entity1,poss tag of word before entity2,poss tag of word after entity1,poss tag of word before entity2 
  constituent path , base syntatic chunk path , typed depandency path (thease feature you can extarct by using stanford parser and depandency parser) 
  you can also try some more feaure.

ONES you extract the features Now use any (multiclass) classifier you like :

SVM (support vector machine) 
 MaxEnt (aka multiclass logistic regression) 
 Naive Bayes

ones you have trained your model you can use it for relation extraction.

Comment: In the point 2 (word based features), the number of words between entities change depending on sentences, so how do you use inconsistent number of features in training on SVM?

Comment: This answer should have mentioned it's source. It's actually taught by Prof. Dan Jurafsky - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mgz2Ma2NzuM

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Rosoka available through Amazon AWS at [Rosoka](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00E6FGJZ0) it provides entity and relationship extraction.